# passing non Zend_Form variables to a ViewScript

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I'm using Zend_Form with a ViewScript decorator. This form will be for managing two fairly simple types of objects but is a big form so I'd like to have a single form / processing function.

So I have this:

```
class GameManagementForm extends Zend_Form{

public function __construct($type='flash'){
    parent::__construct();

   //and later
    $this->setDecorators( array( array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => 'game/game-management.phtml'))));
```

What I would like to do is be able to pass non Zend_Form varaiables to the viewScript. I tried passing a referencing to $this but no such luck. Is there a way to call something like this:

```
$this->setDecorators( array( array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => 'game/game-management.phtml', $arg))));
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [API Docs](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Form/Decorator/Zend_Form_Decorator_ViewScript.html) any options set on the decorator besides separator, placement, and viewScript will be passed to the viewScript as local variables. So:

```
 $this->setDecorators(array(array('ViewScript', array(
      'viewScript' => 'game/game-management.phtml',
      'foo' => 'bar'
 ))));
```

And then in your viewScript 'foo' should be 'bar'.

Comment: cool thanks. would be this->foo in the ViewScript in case anybody stumbles across this. for arrays of data i would just do 'foo'=>$args (although probably obvious.

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention the $this.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass variables to the form displayed out of controller, use the following

```
# controller e.g. controllers/PhotosController.php
$this->view->photos = array(1, 2, 3);
```

and

```
# viewscript of the form e.g. form/photos.phtml
$this->photos = $this->element->getView()->photos;
var_dump($this->photos);
```

You will see dump of array.